# How to use two swing worker instances?

Tags: java, swing, concurrency

i have created `SwingWorker` instance and scheduled it in worker `thread(tAccess = new TimeAccess()).execute())` this instance to access the time. but I need another swing worker instance to continuously access database. How to do this?

```
// when execute both instances ,sometimes GUI become unresponsive. 

tAccess = new TimeAccess()).execute(); 
dAccess = new DataAccess()).execute();
```

code:

```
public class DataAccess extends SwingWorker<Void, ArrayList<TimeTable>> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        int timeRun = 0;
        ArrayList<TimeTable> timeList = null;
        while (timeRun == 0) {
            timeList = TimeTableController.viewTimeTable();
            publish(timeList);

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<ArrayList<TimeTable>> dataList) {
        ArrayList<TimeTable> timeArray = dataList.get(dataList.size() - 1);
        DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        int x = 0;
        for (TimeTable time : timeArray) {
            dtm.setValueAt(time.getCity() + "          " + time.getTime(), x, 0);
            dtm.setValueAt(time.getCity() + "          " + time.getTime(), x, 1);
            x = x + 1;
           // System.out.println(x);
            System.out.println(javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread() + "database thread chkr");

        }

    }

}


 private class TimeAccess extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() {
        int timeRun = 0;
        while (timeRun == 0) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.getTime();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
            String timeNow = sdf.format(cal.getTime());

            publish(timeNow);

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> timeList) {
        String time = timeList.get(timeList.size() - 1);
        clockLabel.setText(time);
        System.out.println(javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
    }

}
```

Comment: Without knowing what you actually _do_ in your workers, we cannot help you.

Comment: i have just upload my 2 worker classes.

Answer (score 3):

The issue seems to that you have an infinite loop here:

```
while (timeRun == 0) {
```

That calls some method:

```
TimeTableController.viewTimeTable();
```

I'm going to assume that this method does not block, or anything sensible. So:

1. The worker loops and, some large number of times a second, calls `publish`; then
2. Publish takes all the data and, every time, updates the entire display table.

This obviously takes up all the EDT's time - trying to keep up with the updating you are asking to it do.

So, well done on using a `SwingWorker`. Think more about your logic.

Comment: process method is invoked asynchronously on the Event Dispatch Thread but why execution does not manage by the EDT ?

Comment: @lahiru I don't understand the question. The whole point is that `process` runs on the EDT and `doInBackground` runs on the worker thread. Calling `publish` is way of publishing objects, in a thread safe manner, from the worker thread to the EDT for display. You are publishing too much and completely overloading the EDT.

Comment: yes, process method runs on the EDT.JAVA DOC mentioned that process method is invoked asynchronously(Occurring at regular intervals) . so how it takes all the EDT's time.

Comment: @lahiru you don't seem to understand what "asynchronous" means or what "thread" means. If I invoke something at interval `t` that takes some time `d > t` then what do you think happens?

Comment: u say that, whole interval takes to run that while loop.am i correct?

Comment: Once again, you don't seem to understand how this works. The `while` loop runs on the background thread. It calls `publish`. At an interval, the EDT gathers published events and calls `process`. It is the `process` method that overloads the EDT.

Comment: yes, i'm sorry interval takes to run that process method on EDT(not "While loop")

Comment: if i add Thread.sleep(); to first swing worker instance ,Is it affect the second swing worker instance ?(i meant that,if both instances execute in same worker thread. )